# SearchView in Collapsing toolbar gets hided when scrolled up

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar in MainActivity with a SearchView in toolbar. When the searchview icon is clicked the searchview gets collapsed in the toolbar. It works fine when the toolbar is collapsed. But if i click on the search icon and scroll up, the collapsed searchview will hide. I want to the collapsed searchview to be visible when scrolled up. I am following 
this link [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)

This is the screen when the collapsing toolbar is collapsed
[image]

Now if i click on the search icon the screen looks like this
[image]

Till now the searchview is working fine. Now if i scroll up the screen looks like this
[image]

Now if i click the search icon, the searchview gets collapsed but it gets hided. So i want the searchview to be collapsed in the toolbar even when the collapsing toolbar is not collapsed.
This is the screen shot which i want when the toolbar is not collapsed and the search icon is clicked

[image]

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/pink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_white"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:elevation="10dp"
    />
```

and this is my MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MaterialSearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




    final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout)          

    findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)    

      findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);

        // hiding & showing the title when toolbar expanded & collapsed
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = false;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_tint));

                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
                    isShow = true;
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));

                } else if (isShow) {
                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(" ");
                    isShow = false;
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_tint));

                }
            }
        });

        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do some magic
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new    MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                //Do some magic
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //Do some magic
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: any one got solution?

Comment: Is any one got solution ??? plz help me... M stuck

Comment: @hasan Shaikh have u got solution???

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with `edittext` and `textchangedlistener`

in `xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack_50"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorBlack_50"
            app:expandedTitleMargin="10dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            //some views

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

in `activity`

```
editTextSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       searchAudio(editTextSearch.getText().toString());
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int s, int b, int c) {}

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int s, int b, int c) {}
});
```